# Kubernetes execute command on all php-fpm pods

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to execute a `chown` command on all my php-fpm pods.

I came to this part:

```
#!/bin/bash
PODS=$(kubectl get pods -n my-production | grep php-fpm | awk -F' *|/' '$2 == $3 && $4 == "Running"' | awk {'print $1'} | column -t )
for POD in $PODS
do
    echo $POD
    kubectl -n my-production exec -it $POD -c php /bin/bash
done

echo "all done"
```

This is entering each specific pod that has a "php-fpm" in its name.

I would like to execute a chown command for each of those pods.

The command that I should run looks like this:

`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/app/current/app/cache`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the command in your script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
PODS=$(kubectl get pods -n my-production | grep php-fpm | awk -F' *|/' '$2 == $3 && $4 == "Running"' | awk {'print $1'} | column -t )
for POD in $PODS
do
    echo $POD
    kubectl -n my-production exec $POD -c php -- chown -R www-data:www-data /var/app/current/app/cache
done

echo "all done"
```

Since you execute a non-interactive command, you don't need the `-it` flags and since the command has arguments, you need a `--` between the kubectl command and the command that you want to run on the Pods.